# How to prepare for a "technical" software engineer phone interview based on CV?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, recruitment

I had an initial phone chat with recruiter and they informed me their hiring process goes something as follows:

- initial recruiter chat (done)
- more technical phone call with a software engineer to dig deeper into my experience on CV - this will be technically oriented
- technical challenge (coding test or take home test)
- on-site 3-4 hour interviews

So my question is - how should I prepare for the technical phone call with an engineer?

The recruiter told me I won't have to solve problems over the phone but I am not quite sure how to prepare for it.

This is what I have done so far:

- made notes of tech we use at work and am planning to make some bullet points about interesting projects I have worked on
- working my way through *Top 100 Python Interview Questions You Must Prepare In 2019* (https://www.edureka.co/blog/interview-questions/python-interview-questions/) and other similar websites
- doing some small coding challenges.

How can I prepare for the second stage to ensure I give it my best shot?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The engineer will be listening for evidence that you **really did** what you have listed on your cv... So it is no sweat if you have that experience...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> more technical phone call with a software engineer to dig deeper into
>   my experience on CV - this will be technically oriented
>
> So my question is - how should I prepare for the technical phone call
>   with an engineer?

Since they will be digging into your experience as represented on your CV

- read your CV over very carefully
- make sure you know of examples you can discuss for everything you have written on your CV
- be prepared to discuss the level of experience for every technology you have mentioned
- find out the technologies used by the employer, and be prepared to relate how the experience on your CV will help you with those technologies

Comment: Should I also spend some time doing problem solving in case they ask me to do it? Or should I instead also focus on things like common algorithms that developers are expected to know and potentially work my way through https://github.com/yangshun/tech-interview-handbook - the thing is the phone call is on Monday (47.5 hours away as of now!)

Comment: I understand I am contradicting myself a little, but I will be completely honest - I am really nervous because i really care about this position and thus want to make sure i am as prepared as possible. HOWEVER, your point is very valid, instead of spreading myself too thin and try to do things I might now need for now, I will take your advice and focus on what I was told I will be asked - already started making detailed notes for each point in the CV so I can refer to those during the phone interview - thank you once more for your help!

Comment: @Ch4osMonkey, a phone call with engineer is usually mostly to figure out if you have some experience with the things you claimed in your CV. If you .Net you might get questions like "what is the difference between string and StringBuilder". You might be asked reasonable details about your previous projects and get in discussion on what (from technical perspective) you did and why. And don't be nervous while on the phone. Just imagine you are going over the former projects with your colleague.

Comment: @AlexanderM thank you for your input - I am fairly confident I will do great but I am just worried they might ask me something that I have an idea of how it works but would need to consult the docs for more details - I have spent a good amount of time making notes about everything on CV and will do some brushing up on some of the tech I have used just in case :)